# How to detect broken image and replace with another?

Tags: php, html

I have a page which displays lots of images from different remote servers.
http://example.com/img/email_star0.png' height='150' />

Now suppose this image is not present, I get a (x) in my html. Is there anyway that I can detect that this image is not present and replace this (x) with a local image without having to check if the file exists on the remote server using Curl (or using JQuery for that matter) and thereby save time? Can this be done locally?

Thanks for your help

Comment: so there is no way of detecting if the image is available (on the server side) and if it is not, replace it with the local image?

Comment: @David What would be a valid php way to do that check?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes this is possible using onerror event:

```
<img src="your_image_source" onerror="this.src='/path/to/local/file'">
```

If the image does not exist, instead of displaying the X, this will show the default image in your local folder

Comment: Obscure HTML attributes for the WIN! You are the boss!!

Comment: Thanks for your kind compliments :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, sorry for the late reply

Comment: Hi, this only works for me if I put the absolute path to the image, ie. from the domain root. Is there a reason for that? How can I use the relative path similar to the original (broken) image? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to check if image exists on remote server without using curl or jQuery. But jQuery snippet bellow reacts on image loading error by replacing it with a local one, maybe that's what you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').error(function(){
     $(this).attr('src', 'http://mysite/myimage.jpg');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'onerror' attribute directly in the image tag:

```
<img src="my_images.jpg" onerror="this.src='my_replacement.jpg'">
```